# JQuery copy and paste in real time a input value into another

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've create a PHP page with a form, where i populate all the inputs with the data taked from the DB.
I need that in the field "Titolo", when the user start to edit/write something, in real time this value must be copy and paste in the field "Meta Titolo".

I suppose that the soluion could be a JQuery, but i don't know how do that :/ I tried something like this, but sure not work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#editor_titolo" ).on("keyup change", function(e) {
      var namer = $('.form-control').attr('#meta_titolo');
      $( namer).text($(this).val());
    });
  });
```

[image]

My form is structured in this way:

```
 <div class="col-6"> 
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-15"> 
                    <form action="" method="POST" name="traduzione_testo">  
                        <label for="titolo" class="form-label form-control-lg">Titolo</label>
                        <input type="text" name='editor_titolo' id='editor_titolo' class="form-control"  style="height: 50px;weight: 100px;" placeholder="Titolo" value="<?= isset($titolo_tradotto) ? $titolo_tradotto: ''?>">
                </div>
                <div class="col-15"> 
                    <label for="meta-titolo" class="form-label  form-control-lg">Meta-Titolo</label>
                    <input type="text" name='meta_titolo' id='meta_titolo' class="form-control"  style="height: 50px;weight: 100px;" placeholder="Meta-Titolo" value="<?=isset($meta_titolo_tradotto) ? $meta_titolo_tradotto: ''?>">
                </div>
                <div class="col-15"> 
                    <label for="link-rewrite" class="form-label  form-control-lg">Link-Rewrite</label>
                    <input type="text" name='link-rewrite' id='link-rewrite' class="form-control"  style="height: 50px;weight: 100px;" placeholder="Link-rewrite"  value="<?=isset($link_rewrite_tradotto) ? $link_rewrite_tradotto: ''?>"> 
                    <button onclick="">Genera Rewrite-link</button> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-15"> 
                    <label for="descrizione" class="form-label  form-control-lg">Descrizione</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name='descrizione' id="descrizione" style="weight: 100px;height: 300px" rows="15" placeholder="Descrizione prodotto"><?PHP echo isset($descrizione_tradotto) ? $descrizione_tradotto : '' ?></textarea>  
                </div>
                <div class="col-15"> 
                    <label for="descrizione_breve" class="form-label  form-control-lg">Descrizione breve</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name='descrizione_breve' id="descrizione_breve" style="height: 70px;weight: 100px" rows="15" placeholder="Descrizione breve prodotto" ><?PHP echo isset($descrizione_breve_tradotto) ? $descrizione_breve_tradotto : '' ?></textarea>  
                </div>
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block mt-2 px-3 mb-3">Salva</button>
                    </form>        
            </div>   
    </div>
```

Comment: Since this isn't related to PHP, I've removed that tag. For future questions, only add tags that are relevant to the question at hand.

Comment: because in the form i added some little snippet of PHP, so i thinked that could be useful

Comment: PHP is a server side language that gets executed on the server, before the page is returned to the client. This question is 100% client side (after the client/browser has received the final result from the server), which means that the PHP is irrelevant at this point. For questions like this, you can even post the generated HTML instead of the source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do with the `.attr("#meta_titolo")`.

But you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#editor_titolo").on("keyup change", function(e) {
    $("#meta_titolo").val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Also please note you are trying to set the value of an input, so you need to use `.val($(this).val())` not `.text($(this).val())`

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#editor_titolo").on("keyup change", function(e) {
    $("#meta_titolo").val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-6">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-15">
      <form action="" method="POST" name="traduzione_testo">
        <label for="titolo" class="form-label form-control-lg">Titolo</label>
        <input type="text" name='editor_titolo' id='editor_titolo' class="form-control" style="height: 50px;weight: 100px;" placeholder="Titolo" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-15">
      <label for="meta-titolo" class="form-label  form-control-lg">Meta-Titolo</label>
      <input type="text" name='meta_titolo' id='meta_titolo' class="form-control" style="height: 50px;weight: 100px;" placeholder="Meta-Titolo" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-15">
      <label for="link-rewrite" class="form-label  form-control-lg">Link-Rewrite</label>
      <input type="text" name='link-rewrite' id='link-rewrite' class="form-control" style="height: 50px;weight: 100px;" placeholder="Link-rewrite" value="<?=isset($link_rewrite_tradotto) ? $link_rewrite_tradotto: ''?>">
      <button onclick="">Genera Rewrite-link</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-15">
      <label for="descrizione" class="form-label  form-control-lg">Descrizione</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" name='descrizione' id="descrizione" style="weight: 100px;height: 300px" rows="15" placeholder="Descrizione prodotto"><?PHP echo isset($descrizione_tradotto) ? $descrizione_tradotto : '' ?></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-15">
      <label for="descrizione_breve" class="form-label  form-control-lg">Descrizione breve</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" name='descrizione_breve' id="descrizione_breve" style="height: 70px;weight: 100px" rows="15" placeholder="Descrizione breve prodotto"><?PHP echo isset($descrizione_breve_tradotto) ? $descrizione_breve_tradotto : '' ?></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block mt-2 px-3 mb-3">Salva</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `attr()` method sets or returns attributes and values which is something you do not need here !

All you need is the *meta_titolo* id

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#editor_titolo" ).on("keyup change", function(e) {
      var namer = $('#meta_titolo');
      namer.val($(this).val());
    });
  });
```

Comment: This will not work, since you use `.text()`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen ahh didn't pay attention to it being an input, thank you for that